# Mapbox visibleFeatures property returns duplicate features

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox

In my project I am using mapBox to show maps and I have features(markers) in the mapView, I am keeping a count of the number of features which are visible in the mapView frame in a UILabel, but the features which the mapBox returns from **mapView.visibleFeatures** has got so many duplicates. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Expert advices needed. Thanks in advance and Happy coding. :-)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are not adding the features (markers) to the map multiple times?

Comment: Can you share the code for how you are adding and accessing the features?